# Complementary Cumulative Distribution Function of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ be three independent and identically distributed (positive) random variables, for which the Probability Density Function (PDF) is as follows:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \alpha \exp\left(- \alpha x\right).
\end{equation}
Define probability function $p(z)$ as
\begin{equation}
p(z) = \begin{cases}
1,     & \text{when $0 < z < c $}    \\
a \exp\left( - b z \right),    & \text{when $z \ge c$} 
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
Note that $\alpha$, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all positive constants. Also note that e.g. for $x_1+x_2 \ge c$ we have $p(x_1+x_2)= a \exp\left( - b (x_1 +x_2) \right)$.

Define $y=p(x_1) p(x_1+x_2) p(x_1+x_2+x_3)$.

I am trying to derive the Complementary Cumulative Distribution Function (CCDF) and the expected value of $y$; I am not necessarly looking for explicit expressions, but I need, at least, to write these expressions as integrals function of $\alpha$, $a$, $b$, and $c$.

- Expected value of $y$:
  $E\left[y\right]= \int_0^\infty  \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty p(x_1) p(x_1+x_2) p(x_1+x_2+x_3)\,  f(x_1) f(x_2) f(x_3) \,dx_1 dx_2 dx_3$
- CCDF $= Pr(y > Y)$ ?

Comment: What is the relevance of $z$?Also, in the above your definition of $y$ is not a random variable, but a product of their PDFs. I think you can do some work to clarify your notation.

Comment: @owen88 $z$ is just a variable. $y$ is the product of three functions that depend on $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$, and since these are random variables, then  $y$ is also a random variable.

Comment: Ok, if $p$ is just a function, then it is still not clear what $p( u \, | \, v)$ would mean (using $u,v$ to avoid confusion with $x_1,x_2,x_3,y,z$ the notation you already use). I assume that this is meant to be interpeted as a conditional probability, but this is still not clear from your notation. Can you do any more to explain why this variable y is of interest?

Comment: @owen88 I have edited the question. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not make the question any clearer (in fact unfortunately, I think introducing the $h$ function makes it less clear). If $h$ or $p$ are functions it does not make sense to `condition' on $x_1$ being fixed. To do this type of conditioning you need a probability measure. Therefore as far as I can tell: $h(x_1 + x_2 | x_1) = h(x_1+x_2)$.

Comment: As I put in my previous comment, it might help if you provide more of the context in which you are solving this question. Is this homework? If so then seeing the original question would enable me to help you more easily. Else if this is a question you have come up with, then understanding the context: eg. why is this variable of interestd, might help.

Comment: The difference is that in $h(x_1+x_2 | x_1)$ the only random variable is $x_2$ whereas in $h(x_1+x_2)$ both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are random variables. This makes a difference for example in the expression of $E[y]$. In other words, for $E[y]$, considering $h(x_1+x_2)$ yields a different result than that if we consider $h(x_1+x_2 | x_1)$.

Comment: I understood what you are claiming before, ("that in $h(x_1 + x_2|x_1)$ the only random variable..."). What I am saying is that this is not a well defined notion for a function: you need a probability distribution, i.e over the $x_i$ or $y$ before you can condition on something. I have tried multiple times to ask you to give some more context; perhaps instead you could show your working so far, or demonstrate a simpler example?

Comment: @owen88 I don't know why I was considering the conditional expression.. Anw, I have edited the question. I hope that it makes sense now. Thank you for your patience.